# firefox-esque tab groups for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin

When I'm working on large projects, I always tend to end up with about 7 or more different tabs open in eclipse.

I'm wondering if there is a plugin available for eclipse that works like Firefoxes tab groups, in that you can group different tabs together and switch between them.  This would make it easier for me to concentrate on my different projects so when i'm working on the "c heeseburger factory" project and something goes wrong on the "hotdog factory" project, I don't have to add a further 8 tabs to what I have open, I can just minimise the current tab group and open a new lot safe in the knowledge once i'm finished with the "hotdog factory" i can have all my "cheeseburger factory" files open in one click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no universally working tab group plug-in, as far as I know.

However, it is possible to use [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) for this reason: when you are working on the "cheeseburger factory" project, you activate a corresponding task, and Mylyn will record a context. When you switch to the "hotdog factory" project, you terminate the currently executed task (the context is saved, but the editors are closed), then open the other task. When you are finished, you simply activate your original task again, and you get back your previous context.

Comment: would the world be interested in one?

Comment: Well, I don't know about the world, but I think, its not for me. I don't use Tab Groups in Firefox, because it does need too much effort from me. I'm better off with Tree Style Tab. And in Eclipse, I rather use name-based navigation (e.g. Open Resource, etc.) rather then open editor based, so I don't think am really interested. But if you tell me one, I could try it out...

Comment: I was searching now for it :D